# Excel Formula - Mapping Values from 3 Columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three rows of data in excel right now. Column A provides an ID but the ID is repeated multiple times (as seen below). The value in Column A will match the value of Column B, though Column A has repeating values. Column B is a unique identifier and Column C is the name affiliated with that unique identifier.

What I'd like to do is have a formula in column D that does the following...

IF A = B then display value of C

Since they're not side to side, it has to search the row of B for each value of A. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
Make    Make ID     Make Name
2       1           Suzuki                                            
2       2           Porsche                                           
7       3           Hyundai                                           
13      4           Austin                                            
20      5           Avanti                                            
21      6           Citroen                                           
21      7           Fiat                                              
21      8           Lancia                                            
31      9           Jensen                                            
31      10          Rover                                             
42      11          Land Rover                                        
42      12          Morgan
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Do this:

`=VLOOKUP($A2, $B$2:$C$whatever, 2, 0)`

This looks up the value A2 in column B and returns the value from column C.

Answer (score -2):

Formula in cell D2 would be as follows

`=if(A2=B2,C2," ")`